# isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_G(k,V)\to V^G$

Tags: representation-theory

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $G$ over a field $k$ and let $G$ act on $k$ trivially. The evaluation at $1\in k$ gives an isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}_G(k,V)\to V^G$, where  $\mathrm{Hom}_G(k,V)$ are the G-equivariant maps and $V^G$ the G-invariants of $V$.

The first part is easy: given $f\in \mathrm{Hom}_G(k,V)$ let $v=f(1)$. Then $g.v=g.f(1)=f(g.1)=f(1)=v$.

What confuses me is the other way around: given a $v\in V,g.v=v$ we can find a $f\in \mathrm{Hom}(k,V)$ such that $f(x)=v,x\in K$. But then $f(g.x)=f(x)=v=g.v=g.f(x)$ thus $f\in \mathrm{Hom}_G(k,V)$. If $x=1$ I would be done, but a priori this is not clear to me. How can I construct such an $f$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $v \in V^G$ the associated map $f\colon k \to V$ is not defined by $f(x) = v$, it's defined by $f(x) = xv$.  It should be easy to check that this is linear and $G$-equivariant.